# Ignition Citadel Error: Failed to create a bridge for topic

Tags: gazebo-citadel, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,

I saw that Ignition is the new "Gazebo" and that it'd be what will be developed moving forward. I wanted to try it out; however, when I run the following command:

```
ros2 run ros_ign_bridge parameter_bridge /TOPIC@ROS_MSG@IGN_MSG
```

I get the following error:

```
Failed to create a bridge for topic [/TOPIC] with ROS2 type [ROS_MSG] and Ignition Transport type [IGN_MSG]
```

I'm running ROS2 Foxy on Ubuntu 20.04. I have followed the installation instructions here: https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/install_ubuntu. I can run Ignition, i.e. I can view the GUI etc.

I can't see what I did wrong; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Best regards,

Frazer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26243/ignition-citadel-error:-failed-to-create-a-bridge-for-topic/) by [FKNoble](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/38763/fknoble/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) on 2020-12-18**:
Just in case, /TOPIC, @ROS_MSG and @IGN_MSG are just templates that you should replace for your specific example. In case you're doing it, could you type the exact example that it's not working?

**Comment by [FKNoble](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/38763/fknoble/) on 2020-12-20**:
My mistake was that I was typing: ros2 run ros_ign_bridge parameter_bridge /TOPIC@ROS_MSG@IGN_MSG, but I should have typed: ros2 run ros_ign_bridge parameter_bridge /keyboard/keypress@std_msgs/msg/Int32@ignition.msgs.Int32.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

In the command you ran, `TOPIC`, `ROS_MSG`, and `IGN_MSG` need to be replaced with a particular topic, ros message type, and ignition message type, respectively.

It looks like you are following the [ROS 2 integration tutorial](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/ros2_integration). The [bidirectional communication section](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/ros2_integration#bidirectional-communication) outlines the format for running a `ros2 run ros_ign_bridge ...` command, but the actual command you want to run is shown in the [publish keystrokes to ROS section](https://ignitionrobotics.org/docs/citadel/ros2_integration#publish-key-strokes-to-ros), which can be found just below the command you ran originally:

`ros2 run ros_ign_bridge parameter_bridge /keyboard/keypress@std_msgs/msg/Int32@ignition.msgs.Int32`

The arguments for this command are also explained in the "publish keystrokes to ROS section" that I just shared with you, so I'd encourage you to read through that link to get a better understanding of this command if needed.

The ros_ign_bridge repository also has a few [examples](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ros_ign/tree/ros2/ros_ign_bridge#example-1a-ignition-transport-talker-and-ros-2-listener) that you can test if needed. I hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [adlarkin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/38815/adlarkin/) with karma: 32 on 2020-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FKNoble](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/38763/fknoble/) on 2020-12-20**:
Thanks so much, that solved my issue. Also, in case it helps anyone else, here's a video showing exactly what to do: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IpZTNyTp9t8&vl=en&ab_channel=GazeboSim.